# Struts2 Upload File, validating size and content type file before send file

Tags: file, validation, upload, struts2, size

I have a problem with Struts 2 and its file upload interceptor. It is have validated my content type and my file size, but the upload process dont stop.
Example my upload limit is 2Mb and user send a file with 500MB, the interceptor struts 2 log that file is too larger, but continue upload file

I'd like to stop the upload process, in error case, beacuse the struts2 have returned to my page only when the sending file is finished.

Thanks

Comment: as per my understanding server can validate it after uploading the file not before.

Comment: I don't think you can as the actual physical upload is handled by the server - standard Http MultiPart form handling and Struts doesn't get control of the request until that request is complete. You may be able to do something via your servlet container/ internet server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in Struts - since Struts doesn't get hold of the response object until your servlet container has finished processing it.

However - most containers have a means of controlling upload file sizes and, for tomcat, this is the maxPostSize parameter (default is 2GB) - as far as I can tell tomcat will count the number of incoming bytes and then exit if this value is exceeded. i.e Tomcat will not continue reading past maxPostSize. Other containers will have similair configuration parameters. I've never used it so I can't be of any further help here.

If you have nested containers/serves (for example, tomcat sitting behind Apache Web Server) make sure you configure the right one

Comment: Hi @user497087 thanks,realy I can't to intercept the request until it is proccessed. I 'm using Jetty with a Apache in front of it. I will see how do to configure Jetty.

Answer (score -1):

You can. Try this. It works..

```
<action name="uploadDocs" class="com.test.myapp.UploadAction" method="upload">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param> <!-- Max 2 MB limit per file-->
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/bmp</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"/>
        <param  name="delay">1000</param>
        <result name="wait">wait.jsp</result> <!-- display custom please wait page -->
    <result name="success">cmresulttemp.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">attachfiles.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">attachfiles.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you want to restrict the total uploaded content size (not per file) add this at the top of your struts.xml file

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10485760" /> <!-- Total 10 MB-->
```

Comment: This solution does not stop the upload.